# Docker Tag Error 25 on gitlab-ci.yml trying to start GitLab Pipeline

Tags: gitlab-ci, testdriven.io

I'm going through the "Scalable FastAPI Application on AWS" course. My gitlab-ci.yml file is below.

```
    stages:
  - docker

variables:
  DOCKER_DRIVER: overlay2
  DOCKER_TLS_CERTDIR: "/certs"


cache:
  key: ${CI_JOB_NAME}
  paths:
    - ${CI_PROJECT_DIR}/services/talk_booking/.venv/

build-python-ci-image:
  image: docker:19.03.0
  services:
    - docker:19.03.0-dind
  stage: docker
  before_script:
    - cd ci_cd/python/
  script:
    - docker login -u "$CI_REGISTRY_USER" -p "$CI_REGISTRY_PASSWORD" $CI_REGISTRY
    - docker build -t registry.gitlab.com/chris_/talk-booking:cicd-python3.9-slim .
    - docker push registry.gitlab.com/chris_/talk-booking:cicd-python3.9-slim
```

My Pipeline fails with this error:

```
See https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/login/#credentials-store
Login Succeeded
$ docker build -t registry.gitlab.com/chris_/talk-booking:cicd-python3.9-slim .
invalid argument "registry.gitlab.com/chris_/talk-booking:cicd-python3.9-slim" for "-t, --tag" flag: invalid reference format
See 'docker build --help'.
Cleaning up project directory and file based variables
ERROR: Job failed: exit code 125
```

It may or may not be relevant but the Container Registry for the GitLab project says there's a Docker connection error.

Thanks

Comment: As the error message show, the problem lies within the tagging name of the docker image. I tried to tag an image with the specified name and it gave the same error. Removing the `_` after `chris` solved the issue. Is this a typo?

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I created a new GitLab account with a new username and things are working now. The underscore does appear to have been the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I created a new GitLab account with a new username and things are working now. The underscore does appear to have been the issue.